# How to render an specific task by id from an store in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuejs3, vue-router4

I am trying to render a specific id when i click on that taskId. Right now when i click on it, it takes me to the route **/tasks/details/id#** and shows me the specific id in the URL but the details page shows me all the tasks instead of the specific one i want to see. I would really appreciate the time to review this and Thank you in advance.

**in VUEX:**
import { createStore } from "vuex";

```
export default createStore({
state: {


tasks: [
  {
    id: 1,
    projectType: "Web Development",
    taskName: "Fixing Bug",
    projectDescription: "Task Assigned to fix navbar bug",
    dateCreated: "12/06/2021",
    duration: 1,
    status: "Completed",
    completeDate: "12/06/2021",
    notes: "difficult task, i posponed copuple of times",
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    projectType: "Python",
    taskName: "Tutorials",
    projectDescription: "Looking at python tutorials",
    dateCreated: "12/06/2021",
    duration: 1,
    status: "Completed",
    completeDate: "",
    notes: "difficult task, i posponed copuple of times",
    taskHistory: [],
  },


],
},

mutations: {
addTask(state, payload) {
  state.tasks.unshift(payload);
},
```

},

```
actions: {
addTask(context, data) {
  const registerTask = {
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
    projectType: data.project,
    taskName: data.task,
    status: data.status,
    duration: data.duration,
    created: data.created,
    completeDate: data.completed,
    notes: data.notes,
    history: data.history,
    projectDescription: data.desc,
  };
  context.commit("addTask", registerTask);
},
},
 getters: {
taskList(state) {
  return state.tasks;
},

getByLength(state) {
  return state.tasks.length;
},

getId: (state) => (id) => {
  return state.tasks.find((task) => task.id === id);
},
},
modules: {},
});
```

**In TASKLIST page:**

```
<template>
<base-card class="wrapper">
<h2>Task Details</h2>
<base-button link :to="'/tasks/add'">Add task</base-button>
</base-card>

<items-list
v-for="task in tasks"
:key="task.id"
:id="task.id"
:project="task.projectType"
:description="task.projectDescription"
:task="task.taskName"
:duration="task.duration"
:created="task.dateCreated"
:complete="task.dateCompleted"
:status="task.status"

 >
 </items-list>
 </template>

<script>
import ItemsList from "../components/layout/ItemsList.vue";

export default {
data() {
return {

};
},
components: { ItemsList },

computed: {
tasks() {
  return this.$store.getters.taskList;
},
detailsLink() {
  // id# passed from ItemsList to find specific id
  return "/tasks/details/" + this.id;
},
},
};
```

**ITEMSLIST** Component: (component that pass the props to TaskList)

```
<template>
<section>
  <base-card class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>{{ project }}</h3>
    </li>

    <li><span>Task Name:</span> {{ task }}</li>
    <li><span> Date Created:</span>{{ created }}</li>
    <li><span> Status: </span> {{ status }}</li>
    <li><span>Duration: </span>{{ duration }} hr</li>
    <li><span>Description: </span> {{ description }}</li>
    <li><span>Id#</span> {{ id }}</li>
    <div class="buttons">
      <base-button link :to="'/tasks/details/' + this.id"
        >Details</base-button
      >
    </div>
  </ul>
</base-card>
</section>
</template>

<script>
import BaseCard from "../ui/BaseCard.vue";
import BaseButton from "../BaseButton.vue";

export default {
props: [
"id",
"project",
"task",
"created",
"status",
"duration",
"description",
 ],

 components: {
 BaseCard,
 BaseButton,
 },

data() {
return {
 
};
},

computed: {
tasks() {
  return this.$store.getters.taskList;
},
getByLength() {
  return this.$store.getters.getByLength;
},
// getId() {
//   return this.$store.getters.taskList.find((task) => task.id === this.id);
// },
 },
 };
 </script>
```

And finally, the **TaskDetails** Page(Will show details using id passed from a prop from the state.$store from VUEX:

```
 <template>
 <base-card class="wrapper">
 <h2>Task Details</h2>
 </base-card>

 <task-items
 v-for="task in tasks"
 :key="task.id"
 :id="task.id"
 :project="task.projectType"
 :description="task.projectDescription"
 :name="task.taskName"
 :duration="task.duration"
 :created="task.dateCreated"
 :complete="task.dateCompleted"
 :status="task.status"
 :notes="task.notes"
 :history="task.history"
 ></task-items>

 <router-view></router-view>
 </template>

 <script>
 import BaseCard from "../components/ui/BaseCard.vue";
 import TaskItems from "../components/layout/TaskItems.vue";

 export default {
 components: { BaseCard, TaskItems },

 data() {
 return {};
 },

 computed: {
 tasks() {
 return this.$store.getters.taskList;
 },
 getById() {
 return this.$store.getters.getId;
 },
 taskId() {
 return this.$store.getters.getId.id;
 },
 },
 };
 </script>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).